# How to select table regrouping by task number and date

Tags: mysql

Here I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  project_nb INT NOT NULL,
  task_nb INT NOT NULL,
  act_date DATE,
  end_date DATE NULL
);

INSERT INTO tasks (project_nb, task_nb, act_date, end_date)
VALUES
(200, 1, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02'),
(200, 2, '2019-09-01', NULL),
(201, 1, '2019-09-21', '2020-02-02'),
(203, 1, '2019-12-01', '2019-12-21'),
(203, 2, '2019-10-01', '2020-02-02'),
(203, 3, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-25'),
(203, 4, '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02'),
(204, 1, '2019-11-01', '2019-11-01'),
(204, 2, '2019-11-01', NULL),
(209, 1, '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02'),
(209, 1, '2019-08-01', '2019-09-22'),
(209, 2, '2019-10-01', '2019-10-10'),
(209, 2, '2019-10-01', '2020-10-10'),
(209, 3, '2020-02-01', NULL),
(209, 3, '2020-02-01', NULL);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/depSvhnygaSxq3P1ckEwuM/1, where I have project number that can be multiple times, task number, activation and end dates.

I would like to count remaining jobs (activated before the day of the row and not ended yet) by week and by job from 1st sept 2019 to today.

I don't know if I have to use stream datas with other language/soft or MySql can do it.

```
Weeks      |   Task 1   |   Task 2   |   Task 3
---------------------------------------------------
01-Sept-19 |
08-Sept-19 |
15-Sept-19 |
...
```

Thank you and sorry for bad English.

Comment: This appears to be a display issue, best resolved in application code

Comment: Search for mysql pivot if you really want to do it in mysql.

Comment: It's not must to use only sql, I have other tools like powerBI but I don't know much about dax or power query. And that m's why I thought to try with sql directly. I did not know about pivotting on mysql, i will look at while I learn BI too. Thank you.